# What is the difference between the two css selectors [class^=test] vs [class|=test]

Tags: css

These two `[class^=test]` and `[class|=test]` matches the same elements as I see.

Is there any real difference or case why should I use one over the other?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Answer (score 6):

```
[class^="test"]
```

The above selects all elements that **starts with class** "test", it will fail to find if the test is second class.

But:

```
[class|="test"]
```

finding elements that matches class, won't show you if the class is "testing"
but will find if the class is "test-ing", the above one will match both. Also , it will fail to find if the test is second class.

```
[class|="test-"]
```

And this case will only accept "test-" and won't accept "test-ing" or a string which starts with "test-", e.g., "test-ing".

Comment: Link to an official definition: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: @deceze That is not actually the official definition.

Comment: @MrL I know, that's why I said "an". It's easier to digest than the actual official one.